# Exported database is showing different size than Cpanel

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am just wondering why the size of exported database is showing different value than Cpanel? For example, the size of the database is showing 1.2 MB in cpanel. I checked using PHPMYADMIN and its displaying 1.1 MB. But after exporting the database in SQL Format (Export method: Quick - display only the minimal options), the size is showing 563 KB.

Can anyone explain why there is such difference in the size?

Comment: I believe the database is optimized when exported (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html) which cleans up empty spaces from updated variable length records, deleted records, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The cPanel database backup option usually includes `DROP TABLE` and `LOCK TABLES` statements, whereas a default phpMyAdmin export does not, so this could explain the slightly increased size of the cPanel Database backup.

However, the large difference (half the size) in the "Quick" export to the "Custom" export seems a bit extreme, unless some of the format options have been changed. Has the "Quick" export outputted the data for instance?!

It's also possible that the cPanel and phpMyAdmin "Custom" options have outputted comments, whereas the "Quick" option may have omitted these. Although this alone wouldn't necessarily account for halving the file size, it could contribute to it.

In short, there are various options that can be set when exporting the database and these can all play a part in the resulting size of the database export.